# Why can't I put mulitple statements into a single event?

Tags: mysql

I made a code that needs to be called 8 times, each time with a different 'x' value, that ranges from 1 to 8.

```
UPDATE schedule
SET worker= (SELECT worker FROM (SELECT * FROM schedule) AS scheduleIn WHERE day = x + 1 AND scheduleIn.hour = schedule.hour)
WHERE day = x;
```

Now, I can tackle this problem in one of two ways as far as I see:

1) Make a loop and call the code with every X value, like this: (Pseudo code)

```
for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
UPDATE schedule
SET worker= (SELECT worker FROM (SELECT * FROM schedule) AS scheduleIn WHERE day = x + 1 AND scheduleIn.hour = schedule.hour)
WHERE day = x;
}
```

2) Call the same code multiple times with differente values. Like this:

```
UPDATE schedule
SET worker= (SELECT worker FROM (SELECT * FROM schedule) AS scheduleIn WHERE day = 1 + 1 AND scheduleIn.hour = schedule.hour)
WHERE day = 1;

UPDATE schedule
SET worker= (SELECT worker FROM (SELECT * FROM schedule) AS scheduleIn WHERE day = 2 + 1 AND scheduleIn.hour = schedule.hour)
WHERE day = 2;

UPDATE schedule
SET worker= (SELECT worker FROM (SELECT * FROM schedule) AS scheduleIn WHERE day = 3 + 1 AND scheduleIn.hour = schedule.hour)
WHERE day = 3;
...
```

You get the point. But both alternatives have it's own problems. The first one's is that I still don't know how to make loops like that in MySQL, despite all the help I got from my previous post.

The second is: It seems like I cannot put more than one statement on a single event, for some reason. I'd really appreciate if somebody would tell me what I'm doing wrong.
.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTxMn.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5hTK.jpg)

Comment: You can try this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html You should create you own logic for your query.

Comment: What do you mean, "needs to be called 8 times"? What is the output as a function of the input? Put the values in a `values` table constant and write one update. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.  Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.